# Replace elements of array with their average

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

Let's say I have a numpy array as such:

```
a = [0, 1, …, i-1, i, i+1, …, j, j+1, …, n]
```

and I'd like to replace of i-th, i+1-th… j-th element with a single one — their average:

```
b = [0, 1, …, i-1, average, j+1, …, n]
```

How would I do that with as compact code as possible?

Comment: did you have a look at [numpy slicing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing)? if so, what didn't work for you?

Comment: That's not a numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice and concatenate arrays

```
   np.concatenate([a[:i], a[i:j].mean().reshape(1,), a[j:]])
```

Example

```
a = np.array(list(range(20)))
i = 5
j = 10

np.concatenate([a[:i], a[i:j].mean().reshape(1,), a[j:]])

array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  7., 10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16.,
       17., 18., 19.])
```